# JQuery Accordion - bottom-up in stead of top-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have a question about the accordion [plugin for jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#overview).
Basically, I've got it to work on my site nicely, there's just one thing that I'd have liked it to do and that is bottom-up opening in stead of top-down.

What I mean by that is that my 3 buttons just stand in the vertical menu (div) in the bottom. And when you click it, they'll slide open but upwards, not downwards.
Is there a way to achieve this easily?
I've gone through the documentation, but can't find any native support for it, so I was wondering if it was possible to do it in the javascript of the plugin itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got my accordion to always to be fixed to the bottom and slide upward:

```
#accordion {
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [animated option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) that controls which animation is used for the widget. I don't know if it supports 'slideUp' or not.  You might want to experiment with the other effects in the UI effects library and/or the default animation effects.  A little investigation may also enable you to create your own effect that does exactly what you want if one of the pre-defined ones doesn't work.  Note that you'll probably also want to change the icons, at least for the selected header.

Comment: Apparently these don't provide a definite answer, I reckon I will have to dive into the JS code to make a "custom" animation...
Icon's and coloring and stuff isn't really a problem seeing I'm doing the styling all custom already.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active

Here it shows which part of the accordion-menu starts as active part...